# Can you assign different default gateways on a per-application basis in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, routing

I have two internet connections (one satellite and one DSL). I want to route all my gaming traffic through the DSL connection and all other traffic through satellite.

Each WAN is served from its own router, however both routers connect to a single ethernet port on my PC (the DSL one is bridged to the other). I can change which WAN I use simply by changing the default gateway in the TCP/IPv4 settings pane.

`Default gateway: 192.168.0.100 = satellite router`
`Default gateway: 192.168.0.200 = DSL router`

[image]

What I want to do is bind certain applications - and all their traffic - to a particular default gateway, e.g. `counterstrike.exe -> 192.168.0.200`. I've tried using ForceBindIP, but I assume it requires two separate NICs to function properly and I only have one.

I've also tried adding the virtual Loopback adapter to Windows 7, with a view to then using that with ForceBindIP, but I wasn't sure how to configure it to actually connect to the internet.

I can't use the routing table to force gateways because I don't know the destination IPs of all of the potential outgoing traffic.

Is there something which will let me change gateways on a per-program basis?

Comment: I have the same requirement on this. Did you finally solve it? How?

Comment: Not exactly. I used manual routing as per Joel Coehoorn's answer below. Luckily, the gaming servers I wanted to route to had static IPs. If your application uses dynamic IPs then I'm still unsure of the best solution. Maybe try buying two NICs and using ForceBindIP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what gaming servers you'll connect to, you can set your default gateway to the satellite connection, and then [enter manual routes](http://www.computerhope.com/routehlp.htm) in windows for your gaming servers that direct them to the dsl line.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in the question I don't always know the destination IPs and am looking for a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't change gateway per-application. (at least none that I know of)

But if your router supports, you can perform QoS on certain applications you want to give preferences.

I've worked with something like that long time ago and you should find it under administration section of your router configuration application.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of running the application in a virtual machine. There you can set a different gateway. You will also need a separate IP than your physical machine, but in the same network.